# ajax auto save input and textarea data in play framwork

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework

I want to auto save data like every some seconds, I had test my code can save input value,but textarea doesn't work.

My form is like this:

```
<from id="my-form" action="@{user.save()}" method="post">
    <input name="user.id">
    <input name="user.name">
    <textarea name="user.intro"></textarea>
</form>
<p class="form-status-holder"></p>
```

js code in the save page

```
<script>
    var timeoutId;
    $('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change
            saveToDB();
        }, 1000);
    });

    function saveToDB()
    {
        var url = "@{user.save()}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#my-form").serialize(),
            success: function(data) { $("#data-result").html($data); }
        });
        // Now show them we saved and when we did
        var d = new Date();
        $('.form-status-holder').html('save success! time: ' + d.toLocaleTimeString());

    }
</script>
```

play user controller

```
public static void save(){
    user.save();
}
```

what is the problem,how could we auto save input value and textarea value both.

Comment: errors in the console?

Comment: chrome console throw an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $data is not defined". but actually，input value was saved success.

Comment: check $("#my-form").serialize() is having values are not.

Comment: $("#my-form").serialize()  is having values. I checked. and the textarea value 'user.intro' in there too.

Comment: create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ here